# RichTextBox Select + SelectionColor does not work

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to highlight code as I am typing it by putting my code inside RichTextBox_TextChanged event handler.

My issue is that the code selects but it's the normal selection with the blue background and white text, like you're doing it with your mouse.

If I then try to type something out, it types in the color I want and the previous selection stays the same. It's all just a mess.

My code:

```
    string hello = "World";
    int index = RTB.Text.IndexOf(hello);
    int length = hello.Length;

    if (-1 != index)
    {
        RTB1.Select(index, length);
        RTB1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
    }
```

What would be a proper way to implement quick syntax highlighting in C#?

Is there anything better than Select using a RichTextBox? Some control that allows you to change the color of bits of text without having to select them and change the color of the selection? I imagine it would be quicker and more convenient that way.

Answer (score 1):

Store the current selected text start/length so you can put it back to the way it was before you changed the color of the text.  Something like:

```
string hello = "World";
int start = RTB1.SelectionStart;
int length = RTB1.SelectionLength;
if (RTB1.Find(hello) != -1) // selects it for you
{
    RTB1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
    RTB1.Select(start, length); // put selection back to the way it was
}
```